# Include placeholder in jQuery serialize

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, serialization, input

I have a form that I am sending over an AJAX call with jQuery's `serialize` function. However, some of my fields may or may not have a value, and if they don't have a value, they may have a placeholder. I was hoping `serialize` would send the placeholder if the value was empty, but in testing that doesn't seem to be the case. Is it possible to have `serialize` include placeholder values when the actual value is empty, or will I have to write up some custom logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to loop over the input's just prior to calling `serialize()`

```
$('#myForm :input[placeholder]').val(function(idx, currVal){
    var placeholder = $(this).attr('placeholder') || '';
    return currVal ? currVal : placeholder ;    
});

// serialize here
```

Above uses `val(function)` which creates loop and treats each element as unique instance

Assumes that it would be acceptable to set the value of the control itself since this would be simplest way.